# How to hide the textbox and float up when an item is selected from listview?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application in which there are certain listview items.Like in the image there are 3 items, A, B, C. initially when user does not select any item, textbox will be hidden.

ListView Items when the TextBox is hidden

[image: ListView Items when the TextBox is hidden]

When the user clicks on any of the item, I want a Textbox with description of that item to be displayed.

TextBox displays , when items from listview is selected

[image: TextBox displays , when items from listview is selected]

Comment: See [Binding to Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#binding-to-collections), section *Master-Detail Binding Scenario*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the code behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MyViewModel m_MyViewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            m_MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
            myGrid.DataContext = MyVM;
        }

        public MyViewModel MyVM
        {
            get
            {
                return m_MyViewModel;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public List<string> MyCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
            }
        }

        private bool isListViewItemSelected;

        public bool IsListViewItemSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return isListViewItemSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                isListViewItemSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsListViewItemSelected");
            }
        }


        private string selectedItem;

        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value != selectedItem)
                {
                    selectedItem = value;
                    if (selectedItem == null)
                    {
                        IsListViewItemSelected = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IsListViewItemSelected = true;
                    }
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTxtString");
                }
            }
        }

        public string SelectedTxtString
        {
            get
            {
                //return SelectedItem;
                return "\"" + SelectedItem + "\" is selected!";
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {

        #region DisplayName

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the user-friendly name of this object.
        /// Child classes can set this property to a new value,
        /// or override it to determine the value on-demand.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

        #endregion // DisplayName

        #region Debugging Aides

        /// <summary>
        /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
        /// a public property with the specified name. This 
        /// method does not exist in a Release build.
        /// </summary>
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
            // public, instance property on this object.
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
            {
                string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

                if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                else
                    Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
        /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
        /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might 
        /// override this property's getter to return true.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

        #endregion // Debugging Aides

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members


        #region IDisposable Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this object is being removed from the application
        /// and will be subject to garbage collection.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.OnDispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Child classes can override this method to perform 
        /// clean-up logic, such as removing event handlers.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void OnDispose()
        {
        }

        #endregion // IDisposable Members

    }
}
```

And this in the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">

    </ListView>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedTxtString, Mode=OneWay}" 
             Visibility="{Binding IsListViewItemSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Note that your `IsListViewItemSelected` is always set to `true`, regardless whether `SelectedItem` is null or not. Besides that, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a OneWay Binding (like the Text and Visibility Bindings of the TextBox in your example) is pointless. UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect in TwoWay of OneWayToSource Bindings, and has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: It's also pointless to write a BoolToVisibilityConverter yourself. There is already one in the framework.

Comment: I wrote it like this, because in the question there was not a de-selection of all ListViewItems involved...  But you are right of course. There should be a check for SelectedItem being null...

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of .NET having implementation of that converter...
Thank you for the tip!

Comment: And thanx for the comments about the UpdateSourceTrigger! They really help me understand the binding process!

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding to bind the visibility flag of the text box to the current selected ListView Item.

In your Controller or ViewModel implement a property for the SelectedItem

```
public object SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

Bind it in the ListView to the SelectedItem property

```
<ListView
    ...
    SelectedItem={Bining Path=SelectedItem}/>
```

Use a second property to determine if a ListView item is selected

```
public Visibility TextBoxVisibility=> SelectedItem != null 
    ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible 
    : System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

In your xaml bind the Visibility property to the IsSelected property

```
<TextBox
    ...
    Visibility={Bining Path=TextBoxVisibility}/>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Do not forget to fire a property change notification for the view model's SelectedItem and TextBoxVisibility properties. Also consider not to use an additional property at all, but just bind the TextBox's Visibility also to SelectedItem with a Binding Converter, or alternatively have a Style with a DataTrigger on SelectedItem that sets the Visibility.

Comment: yes, right. Within the property there must be of course a OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem)), otherwise the Ui will not know when the value has changed

Comment: Not only `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem))` but also `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxVisibility))`, because TextBoxVisibility must be reevaluated when SelectedItem changes.

Comment: I am able to show the description in the textbox, but it always leaves the space for the textbox. The textbox is not hidden, only the content inside the  box is hidden. I want to hide the text box also, and it should be visible only when the user clicks on the item. Can you please help regarding this.